# SELECT TOP 1 without ORDER BY Issue ignores WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table that contains unique codes.  To generate a new unique code we are using an approach found in the below SQL statement and uncovered cases where the `NOT EXISTS` statement seemingly allows rows through that exist.

There is no concurrency issues as this was proven out in a sandbox using a single query being ran against SQL Server 2016.  If we place the `ORDER BY` statement it suddenly works as expected.  It appears as if without the `ORDER BY` that this query is conditionally ignoring the `WHERE` clause.  In the event all codes collide I would expect `@code` to either be NULL or remain it's initial state of 0.

```
DECLARE @code int = 0;

    select  @code = Code from (
        SELECT top 1 randoms.Code
        FROM (
            VALUES 
            (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
            (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
            (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
            (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
            (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT))
        ) randoms (Code)
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TEST_Codes uc WHERE uc.Code = randoms.Code)
    ) c;


    SELECT 
        c.code,
        ud.*
    FROM (VALUES (@code)) as c(Code)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_Codes ud
        ON ud.Code = c.Code
```

This statement will allow duplicates to be returned, which is baffling due to the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` statement.

If we change the definition of the view `c` to be `) c ORDER BY c.Code` it suddenly works.  Why is this?

Comment: Sql Server does not guarantee how many times it will execute compute scalars. It is possible the reference in the `where` is using a different value than the one selected but when you add an order by it materialises it and only calculates it once per row.

Comment: why would you put order by and top 1 since your also checking if the value already exist from test_codes?

Comment: why would you put order by?

Comment: What makes you think the `ORDER` by is just masking the issue? And why are you using such a cursive query in the first place? `ORDER BY` guarantees a deterministic result, which outside a `CLUSTERED INDEX` your query will not be.

Comment: I guess I do not understand why this is so complicated. Are you inserting just one random code? Or randomly matching a code with values for a que?

Comment: This is to get a single code that doesn't exist in the Codes table.  Make that table, make Code the primary key, put 200,000 rows in it and run that query yourself... it returns a row in the bottom statement where the code exists despite the where not in

Comment: Clarity, it doesnt always, in 10k runs 300ish hit the case where it returned a code that defies the NOT EXISTS clause

Comment: Is this for an INSERT or a SELECT statement. meaning, is this your method for inserting new IDs in the code? Related, is this so you can perform mass inserts?

Comment: Not mass insert, a single row at a time.  Codes expire and are deleted at short intervals.  We saw the issue in the insert tests and decided to write the query here to see if it was a concurrency problem or if the query was having issues.  Local sandbox, running exactly that query we found cases where it set @code to a code where it existed.  So what I describe was not an insert problem.

Comment: @martin smith - you need to put that comment as an answer, thats the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sql Server does not guarantee how many times it will execute compute scalars and similar expressions. It is possible the reference in the where is using a different value than the one selected but when you add an order by it materialises it and only calculates it once per row.

If you are on 2014 or above you can use an extended events session on [`query_trace_column_values`](http://www.queryprocessor.com/query-trace-column-values/) to see this happening.

```
DECLARE @TestCodes TABLE(Code int)
dbcc traceon(2486);
set statistics xml on;

    select  Code from (
        SELECT randoms.Code
        FROM (
            VALUES 
            (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
            (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
            (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
            (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
            (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT))
        ) randoms (Code)
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TestCodes uc WHERE uc.Code = randoms.Code)
    ) c
     option(recompile);


set statistics xml off;
dbcc traceoff(2486);
```

[image]

[image]

The column `Union1005` is output from the constant scan at the top right. It is also referenced again in the join predicate. At this point it is re-evaluated and returns a different number.

You may be able to hack around with the query and get it to only be evaluated once but nothing is guaranteed. The only 100% safe way is to materialise the random numbers up front (e.g. into a temp table) before doing the check so you are guaranteed that they aren't going to be recalculated and change under you.

---

An example of hacking about with the SQL to get a non guaranteed result is below. I would not use this as it has the disadvantages that it it still guarantees nothing and also even if it works if you pick the top 1 off it your "random" numbers will no longer be as well distributed. It introduces a bias for lower numbers.

```
select  Code from (
    SELECT TOP 5 randoms.Code
    FROM (
        VALUES 
        (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
        (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
        (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
        (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
        (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT))
    ) randoms (Code)
    order by Code
    ) T
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TestCodes uc WHERE uc.Code = T.Code)
```

[image]

This materialises it and the value output from the sort is the same as that used in the nested loops predicate.

[image]

Comment: He did ask `Why is this?` Is the OP's method best? If unsupported is an option, sure (though that is hardly a wise business strategy) Great answer @Martin.Smith. I love the details and made sharing with my fellow DBAs a lot of fun

Comment: This problem is actually a lot more complex, but we solved it.  Rand and newid are both inappropriate for different reasons. As far as scalar execution issues go, you cannot put rand directly in a function, but you can put rand in a view, and then select from the view in a function, and unlike calling rand directly, calling that wrapper function will produce different values every time. Anyway, a better method is calling crypt_gen_random: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2010/09/09/rand-vs-crypt_gen_random/ and casting it to int or bigint.

Comment: Concurrency is a separate problem, and the "summary" comment in this thread (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8dc6db31-b3b1-4d58-b13f-095eda85c3f4/inserts-only-if-not-exists-in-the-highly-concurrent-system?forum=transactsql) outlines every possible solution, which ones fail, which ones work but are slow, and finally describes *the best* one that uses a custom app lock on the value itself. While one thread successfully claims the right to insert a particular value, all others fail immediately without any errors and loop back to retry a new code without wasting any time.

Comment: @Triynko nice! I did not know about that function! Although, `RAND() returns the same value for each row. CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM() on the other hand gets re-invoked for every row` [SQLITY.NET](http://sqlity.net/en/2259/crypt_gen_random/). Also, SQLPerformance has a great article on avoiding random collisions in your application. [Generate random integers without collisions](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/random-collisions)

Answer (score 1):

**The Hypothesis**

You need a function that creates 5 random values that you want to ensure are not from a table that holds your code values.

We assume your TEST_CODE does not contain duplicates either, and together with the TOP 1 operator the developer can fairly assume his numbers will always be random.

**THE PROBLEM**

@Martin.Smith makes some good observations about the way this hack...and yes, it is a hack method. Functions do not allow RAND() function, and what you seek is not so much a solution as a workaround. Note their reason for denying NEWID()

> Invalid use of side-effecting or time-dependent operator in 'newid()'
> within a function.

What will Microsoft say? They clearly did not intend to allow Non-deterministic functions so you may not be supported here anyways.

Instead, treat this like the Insert operation that it is. You only care about one random value where the only requirement is that it not match any of the existing codes, whether active or passive.

**ADDED -** Furthermore, you want to make your code portable, perhaps even in a job. Use a stored procedure instead.

**Testing Methods:**

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Codes (Code INT, ud NVARCHAR(50) )
GO

DECLARE @COUNT INT = 1;
WHILE (@Count < 100000)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Test_Codes (Code, ud)
        VALUES (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)
                 , 'PoliceNumber[' + CAST(@Count AS NVARCHAR(7) ) + ']')
    SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1 
    END
GO
```

**An Alternative Solution**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.USP_Code_INS (@Name NVARCHAR(100) )
AS
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Test_Codes (Code, ud)
        SELECT TOP 1 B.Code, @Name
        FROM Test_Codes A
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN (  SELECT randoms.Code
                            FROM (
                                VALUES 
                                (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
                                (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
                                (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
                                (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT)),
                                (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT))
                            ) randoms (Code) ) B ON B.Code = A.Code
        WHERE A.Code IS NULL
END
GO
```

Note the `PREDICATE` here is a simple `NULL` comparison. You are **guaranteed** to get a unique value with a solution that is tabular. If you are concerned by the occasion that no rows will be inserted, then add a fail-safe check (*insert operations are expensive*).

```
SELECT TOP 1 B.Code, @Name
        FROM Test_Codes A
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN (table of NEWID() rows) B
WHERE A.Code IS NULL
```

You join the tables by any matching rows based on the smallest table (B) and run a predicate that removes any result where Test_Codes has a match. The predicate uses a boolean comparisons of NULL or not NULL, which the optimizer is highly efficient at guessing and sorting through.

This is a set-based solution and fundamentally is how relational languages work.

```
/* Dynamic Method. Allows to create a job that is simple as a flag to optimize */
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.USP_Code_INS2 (@BatchNumber INT, @Name NVARCHAR(100) )
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @BatchNewID NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'(CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT))'
           , @Count INT = 1
           , @SQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
           , @ParmDefinitions NVARCHAR(100) = N'@Name NVARCHAR(100)'
     /*  Dynamically create newid() table to flag-size. */
     WHILE @Count < @BatchNumber AND @BatchNumber > 1
        BEGIN
            SET @BatchNewID = @BatchNewID + N'
                                , (CAST((abs(CHECKSUM(newid())) % 1000000) AS INT))'
            SET @Count = @Count + 1
        END
    /* Now insert into SQL statement */
    SET @SQLStatement = N'INSERT INTO Test_Codes (Code, ud)
        SELECT TOP 1 B.Code, @Name
        FROM Test_Codes A
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN (  SELECT randoms.Code
                            FROM (
                                VALUES ' + @BatchNewID
                        +   N') randoms (Code) ) B ON B.Code = A.Code
        WHERE A.Code IS NULL'
    --PRINT @SQLStatement
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStatement, @ParmDefinitions
            , @Name = @Name
END
```

**Conclusion**

- Avoid functions as it over-complicates your solution.
- Stored Procedures offer a **clear**, simple and thus manageable solution.
  Microsoft provides a lot of solutions, so utilize what they are made for.

> *Benefits of Stored Procedures*
>
> • **Precompiled execution**: SQL Server
> compiles each Stored Procedure once and then re utilizes the execution
> plan. This results in tremendous performance boosts when Stored
> Procedures are called repeatedly.
>
> • **Reduced client/server traffic**: If
> network bandwidth is a concern in your environment then you’ll be
> happy to learn that Stored Procedures can reduce long SQL queries to a
> single line that is transmitted over the wire.
>
> • **Efficient reuse of code and programming abstraction**:
> Stored Procedures can be used by multiple users and client programs. If you utilize them in a planned
> manner then you’ll find the development cycle requires less time.
>
> • **Enhanced security controls**: You can grant users permission to
> execute a Stored Procedure independently of underlying table
>
> MSDN - [Difference between a stored procedure and function](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pradeepsvs/2014/10/08/difference-between-a-stored-procedure-and-function/)

Comment: Modified Again to add details and maintain clarity

Comment: The actual code we had was the roj solution you offered and it lived in a sproc and that is what lead us to evaluate how duplicate key exceptions were encountered.  We did the roj first into the @code variable then did the insert.  We were getting an occurence of 300ish duplicate keys per 20k operations... thus what brought me here.  Your loop is a possible solution but 1 code being checked at a time was something we were attempting to avoid...

Comment: @VulgarBinary I was hoping that you would take what I was saying fundamentally. The Insert statements will never cause duplicates, but if you think 5 rows of NEWID() is too small, add more...a lot more. I noted the loop because that can prevent broken inserts (when it does not insert). Proof your code, run Checks BEFORE insertion. My first proc will never produce a duplicate row. Remember, Comparing rows will still be significantly less expensive than attempting zero-insert statements over and over. make your code simple, legible, and use methods as they were designed.

Comment: I'm working on this too. I created 3 working versions prior to the problematic one.  The original variations materialized the random set using combinations of (recursive CTE, non-recursive CTE, temp table, table variable), and all variations built the sql string to pass to sp_executesql because the 'top X' selector was an input parameter to the procedure.  These all performed an order of magnitude slower than the direct approach of hard coding X random values and avoiding dynamic sql, and that's when we ran into this surprise where it doesn't materialize the random numbers without an order by.

Comment: The last implementation with the 'insert into select from' will fail occasionally for the same reason the separate select + insert will fail; it will occasionally choose random numbers that exist in the table, unless it's also a hack that causes the set to materialize the same way the 'order by' does.

Comment: A final thing I wanted to mention is that the expected number of codes in use at any given time is going to be very low (1% of 1 million possible with very short expiration times), so this is an optimistic approach where it's very unlikely all 5 random values will be in use. Zero failures in billions of iterations in the slower, working implementations.

Comment: @Triynko You mentioned variable columns in sp_executesql: SQL Server expects columns, so you need to hardcode the columns by assuming the order of the variables in the stored proc. Example: `DECLARE @PARTIAL_SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'EXEC sp_executesql 5, @Name, @Col3'` This will allow SQL Server to treat your variables like it would with a column in the predicate `WHERE [Col] = @Name`. Lets just say I had to hardcode sp_send_dbmail because of a known bug with Microsoft and OLE Automation!